Validation `Required` is not working with radiobtn when using ngFor in Reactive forms
I have a dynamic reactive angular form which builds forms and populates questions inside it dynamically according to questions types retrieved from the database. the problem is the required validation (native HTML5 validation ngNativeValidate) is not working when I add it inside a *ngFor loop
in my form builder I have this part
<div class="row" *ngSwitchCase="'radiobtn'">
      <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-6 pt-0">{{question.label}}</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let opt of question.options; let i = index">
          <label class="form-check-label" [attr.for]="question.key+opt.key">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" [name]="question.key" [formControlName]="question.key"
[id]="question.key+opt.key" [value]="opt.key" required />
            {{opt.value}}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

I have ngNativeValidate in the form tag and I have new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required) in the FormGroup builder.
This code is supposed to apply required validation check but it's not working. when I remove the for loop and make it static the validation works. what is the reason here.
Note: my Angular version is 10

please share a simple stackblitz with the issue happening, I can see you are not implementing form properly, you are mixing template driven and reactive forms

@NarenMurali you said that I am mixing template driven and reactive forms because I have both formControlName and ngModel? yes, but even when I remove the ngModel it still not working. I will edit my question to avoid conflicts

Yes, but require a stackblitz for validating, it could be a bug also, but need to check

something like this link stackblitz

input[radio] needs to have both [name] and [attr.name] to be set.

When working with native validations always prefer Template Driven Forms, because if you go for template driven, the validation you add, will not trigger the native HTML validations.
HTML:
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1 class="display-5">Radio Buttons in Angular</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row custom-wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- Form starts -->
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #actorForm="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
        <!-- Gender -->
        <div class="group-gap">
          <h5 class="mb-3">Gender</h5>
          <div class="d-block my-3">
            <div *ngFor="let gender of questions[0].genders; let i = index">
              <label [for]="gender">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="gender"
                  [id]="gender"
                  [(ngModel)]="genderVal"
                  [value]="gender"
                  required
                />
                {{ gender }}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <!-- Form ends -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

TS:
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('actorForm') registrationForm: NgForm;
  isSubmitted = false;
  questions: { genders: string[] }[] = [{ genders: ['Male', 'Female'] }];
  genderVal = '';

  // Submit Registration Form
  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.registrationForm.valid));
    if (!this.registrationForm.valid) {
      return false;
    } else {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.registrationForm.value));
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
But here is an example of reactive driven forms, the gotcha you need to know is that.
When you add a validation, the corresponding directive also needs to be present in HTML, that is why we have required attribute.
HTML:
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1 class="display-5">Radio Buttons in Angular</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row custom-wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- Form starts -->
      <form
        [formGroup]="registrationForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
        ngNativeValidate
      >
        <!-- Gender -->
        <div class="group-gap">
          <h5 class="mb-3">Gender</h5>
          <div class="d-block my-3">
            <div *ngFor="let gender of questions[0].genders; let i = index">
              <label [for]="gender">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="gender"
                  [id]="gender"
                  formControlName="gender"
                  [value]="gender"
                  required
                />
                {{ gender }}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <!-- Form ends -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  isSubmitted = false;
  questions: { genders: string[] }[] = [{ genders: ['Male', 'Female'] }];

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {}

  /*########### Form ###########*/
  registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    gender: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });

  // Submit Registration Form
  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.registrationForm.valid));
    if (!this.registrationForm.valid) {
      return false;
    } else {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.registrationForm.value));
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Here is my original code which is not working [link]https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-demo-reactive-forms-i7g2c5

@MohammadAM I shared the solution for template driven and reactive in my answer, please go through it and let me know if any doubts

Yes, your example is working fine with reactive forms but it stops working when I start binding name and formControlName attributes dynamically. you can see that in my updated code here [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-demo-reactive-forms-i7g2c5?file=README.md]

@MohammadAM even if it's dynamic the name you set must match what you set in form builder group that is the problem

yes they match [name]="question.key" [formControlName]="question.key" and here is the ts code      group[question.key] = new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required); but still not working

@MohammadAM Thanks for your patience, it seems like a bug, feel free to raise a github issue on angular official github page

no worries and thanks for your help. just posted an issue in Angular's github page
